# 90s fantasy book about evil sorcerer building tower using human remains as mortar

Tags: story-identification, magic, wizards

I believe the book series was a trilogy.

The main heroine was a white-haired mage/sorceress whose birth was orchestrated by magical beings in order to combat evil mages/sorcerers. Her companion was Death, who I remember she fell in love with(!) and she dies/ascends at the end of the trilogy after defeating evil.

A specific detail that I remember is that the evil Mage/sorcerer is building a tower and using human remains as mortar.

Comment: And I did mean death as in a person she actually interacted with and fell in love with towards the end of the series.

Answer (score 7):

This is "[Wizard of the Grove](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0886778190)" by Tanya Huff.

This review on Amazon matches a lot of your description;

> A lengthy prequel pits Rael, son of the hamadryad against the evil
>   wizard, Kraydak. Rael survives to beget a line of kings who are part
>   Elder Race. Eventually Crystal, the true heroine of this duology is
>   born. Kraydak, the wizard also survives. He has been waiting through
>   many boring thousands of years for the birth of Crystal, the only
>   human who might give him a magical run for his continuing existence.
>   Meanwhile he amuses himself by building towers with human blood as
>   mortar, torturing various walk-ons, etc.--even in this early novel,
>   Tanya Huff writes zingy, attention-getting prose about evil--you gotta
>   hate her bad guys, even though they're often her most interesting
>   characters. Presumably the good guys should be interesting, too. My
>   only problem with Crystal is that she doesn't have room to grow. She
>   starts out as a total knock-out with emerald eyes and silver hair, is
>   born into the royal family, and is the world's most powerful wizard,
>   except for Kraydak.

Oh, and one of the characters is apparently named Lord Death.

[image]

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RitaDeLaTorre - Don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted.