# Fantasy book, main character is named Crystal, has seven goddesses within her, and Death as companion

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title to a fantasy book. Its main character's name is Crystal and she has seven goddesses within her. Her companion is Death and at the end of the book she ascends into the heavens with him to create their own universe. I know it's not a lot but I read it a couple years ago and would like to read it again!

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76677/looking-for-title-on-fantasy-book-most-likely-from-the-90s/76684#76684

Comment: Possible duplicate of [90s fantasy book about evil sorcerer building tower using human remains as mortar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76677/90s-fantasy-book-about-evil-sorcerer-building-tower-using-human-remains-as-morta)

Comment: @Mithrandir There hasn't been an acceptance here as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: There has been no acceptance that this is the right answer, the question is therefore not a dupe as per our Story-id duplicate policy.

Answer (score 8):

This is the series: [Wizard of the Grove](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43855-wizard-of-the-grove), by Tanya Huff.

The main character is Crystal, born of the seven gods.

Her companion is Death.

A brief review can be found [here](https://www.sfsite.com/01b/wiz49.htm).